# select with limit and update table. Limit not working fine. sql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update thable with select using limit 
It's update table fine when we enter "limit" only with one parameter in select query like `(limit 50)`

But when select with "limit" like (`limit $sqlFrom, $sqlTo`) it updates the table but skip 2nd (51 to 100) records and again start updating from 101.

It skip every 2nd 50 records

Where is the problem???

Here is the code

```
$sqlFrom  = 0;
$sqlTo    = 50;

for($try = 0; $try < 6; $try++) 
{   

 $res = mysql_query("select * from table_name where underprocess = 0 limit " . $sqlFrom . "," . $sqlTo);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
     $id = $row['id'];

    mysql_query("update table_name set underprocess = 1 where id = " . $id) or die('error');
    echo $id;

 }


print '<hr/>';
if($sqlFrom != 0)
{
    $sqlFrom += $sqlTo;
}
else
{
    $sqlFrom = $sqlTo;
}
}//for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as expected

When you update rows 1-50 based on your first iteration, you set `underprocess = 1`. These are ignored in the 2nd call because ask for rows `underprocess = 0`.

So rows 51-100 in the 1st query are now rows 1-50 for your 2nd query if you like.

You don't need to change your LIMIT range because you always want the "first" 50.

**NOTE**

Your LIMIT isn't guaranteed anyway because you have no ORDER BY.